# Future of Android development IDE, eclipse or Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-studio

Currently I am using Eclipse ADT 23.00 and in [Google I/0 2014](https://www.google.com/events/io), [Android Studio 0.8 beta](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) has been released.

As Android Studio gets closer to a stable version release, Google stated that after release it becomes the official developing environment, so which one is going to be the better option in future?

Comment: it is clearly stated on the android studio download page: `Android Studio (...) will be the official Android IDE once it's ready.`

Answer (score 2):

For future development and upcoming projects it is recommended to use Android Studio in combination with gradle.

Comment: ok, can you know when android studio stable version is going to release?

Comment: @keyboardsurfer absolutely agree, though this kind of question is a little bit holywar

Comment: Android Studio is already a great tool! Better than Eclipse in my opinion.

Comment: @user3395433: It will be released when it will be released.

Comment: can any on konw tool to design android layout faster other than android studio?

Comment: @user3395433 lots of people are already using AndroidStudio (including big companies) and are mostly much more satisfied with it than with Eclipse, check this [link](https://www.infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/eclipse-is-dead-for-android-development-and-i-helped-kill-it)

Comment: Stable version?  Never!

Answer (score 2):

I can't emphasize the following enough.
Your IDE is not and should not be your build system.
The real question is ant vs. Maven vs. Gradle, etc.

Once you have a standardized and widely supported command-line build system, developers on a project should be free to use whatever IDE they wish. IDE artifacts should never be checked in to source control.

I've worked with IntelliJ, and then Android Studio when it first came out, on a project with a Maven build, and had no problem on a team where some used Eclipse and some IntelliJ / Android Studio. I found Android Studio to be better in many ways, but then I'd been a long-time IntelliJ user.

Comment: i don't entirely agree with this. Eclipse is itself kind of a build system. For simple projects you don't really want/need to learn the configuration language of a build system.

Comment: Oh bearded one... Got any reasons for that ad-hominim in the first sentence?

Comment: Re: ad-hominim. Yes. As a consultant, I often see teams struggling with this. Yes, if you are are a hobbyist working on a small project by yourself, it probably doesn't matter, but for anything that has to be maintained, have a repeatable build, involves more than one developer, etc., the question of "which IDE" just isn't important, and obscures the point that what's needed is a solid, non-interactive way to build. Choice of IDE should be left to the individual developer, and not impact the "official" build. Yet lots of people waste time and effort trying to share IDE configurations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is hard working machine and i strongly recommend you to change your working directory!
From the rest to workplaces the better one for me is Android Studio.

Firstly it is based on **IntelliJ IDEA** which i like a lot and yes as you mentioned it is going to the official Android IDE after it's release.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Android then I suggest of using Android studio for development since its an official release and will get stable soon.
It has many features that will increase the developer productive such as

- Template-based wizards
- Lint Tool
  etc...

If are comfortable with Eclipse then I suggest to stick with it until Google lunch a full fledge stable Android studio.